# display "Additional information " below " Details" in product view page

Tags: product-view

please check the link :

http://hotwheelstoys.in/totaltoys2/var/www/html/totaltoys/happy-hours-scribblez.html

i want to display "additional information" below "Details"

this is view.phtml = > http://pasted.co/7bdb70a6

please help me to find solution

Comment: have you used any extension to add tabs in your view page.?

Comment: yes we are using customized theme

Comment: then you need to disable the tabs and then display the details in the order you want

Comment: is i have to check in theme configuration ?